# Looping through a related model and comparing id's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, for-loop

The relation is that a user has many treatments and a treatment belong to user, one-to-many.

Now i want to print out all the users that have this particular treatment

Inside my treatments `show` view i have this double loop

```
<% User.all do |user| %> 

  <%= user.treatments.each do |t| %> 

    <% if (t.id).to_i == (@treatment.id).to_i %> 
      <%= link_to user.name, user_path(user) %><br />
    <% end %>

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

if i change `<% User.all do |user| %>` to `<%= User.all do |user| %>` it prints out everything in my users table

can you guys spot why im not getting any users ?

i put a message in the beginning of the inner loop and it didnt display either, guess the problem is there but im not seeing it

Comment: "treatment belongs to user", "all users that have this treatment", "one-to-many" - don't these statements contradict each other? Are you sure it's not "many-to-many"?

Comment: If treatment belongs to user, then only one user can have this treatment.

Comment: Also, you don't need parentheses around ids. It can be simply `t.id.to_i`, it makes no difference (in this case).

Comment: yeah i know i dont need it, infact i dont need the `.to_i` function at all, i was experimenting with it while i was debugging and forgot to remove it, and your right about the relation as well it was many to many lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.all` returns an array. Array doesn't accept a block. Most likely, you want to do `.each` but forgot to write it. Try this:

```
<% User.all.each do |user| %>
```

but a better way is to not iterate all users like this, but get the correct list from the database directly.

Comment: Yes that was excatly what i was forgetting ! :)